# Probability question involving chess.

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows:
Chess pieces are randomly drawn from a bag and placed on a table. The table has 3 black and some white pieces on it. Another piece is randomly drawn from the bag and placed on the table. Now, instead of drawing from the bag, one chess piece is randomly picked up from the table. The color of the chess piece picked up from the table is black. What is the probability that the last piece that was drawn from the bag was black?

$(a) \frac{4}{7}$

$(b) \frac{4}{5}$

$(c) \frac{4}{2}$

$(d) \frac{4}{6}$

I think option (c) is obviously incorrect because it is greater than 1. Other than this I have no idea how to proceed. I think the required probability should be $\frac{13}{29-x}$ where $\mathit {x}$ is number of white pieces on the table, but I am unable to find $\mathit {x}$.

Comment: Why not edit the question with the calculations you've made to reach $13/(29-x)$? That way we can help you fix the possible errors. This is an exercise of conditional probability. In these cases it helps a lot to define clearly the different events and calculate their probabilities individually, and then use the formula for conditional probability. Another thing that helps is assuming particular cases if you're having troubles, like assuming there was exactly $1$ white piece out.

Comment: Assuming that the probability to draw a black or white chess from the bag is the same you have that your conditional probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Black from the bag}|\text{Black from the table}]=\frac{\frac{4}{4+x}}{\frac{3}{4+x}+\frac{4}{4+x}}=\frac{4}{7}$$

Comment: 1. What is $\mathit {x}$ that you have assumed?                                                                     
2. How P(Black from the bag) = $\frac{4}{4+x}$?                                                                              
3. How P(Black from the table) = $\frac{3}{4+x}$? Kindly explain.

Comment: @AnilCh 3 black chess pieces are on the table, so 13 black pieces are in the bag. Similarly, $\mathit {x}$ white pieces are on the table, so $\mathit {16-x}$  white pieces are in the bag. So P(piece drawn from bag is black) = $\frac{13}{13+16-x}$ which is $\frac{13}{29-x}$

Comment: You're missing two things: First, is that with how the solutions are made, it is probable that the solution assumes the bag has "infinite" pieces, and not only sixteen for each color, so the probability of being black from the bag is always $1/2$; Second is that this is a "conditional probability" problem, because you want the probability of piece drawn from the bag black *knowing* that the one picked up from the table was also black. You have to use the conditional probability formula.

Comment: @AnilCh Okay I understood. Thank you so much.